How can i resolve this inconsequent error on the mail server?
I have a new user/new email powershell script.
In the new email part i try to connect to exchange.server via a remote session to run a few commands to create the email part. Sometimes it runs without an issue, but every now and then i get the following error.
[exchange.domain.com] Connecting to remote server exchange.server.com failed with the following error message : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
I have scoured the internet for solutions, checked every thing i can check and then it runs without this error 99 times and randomly comes back with the error 10 times in a row. It doesnt matter if someone is connected to the server. The winrm check
I have tried Disconnect PSSESSION on the times it does work, no success i have changed the entire code block no success. I tried using UPN instead of SAMAccountName, no success.
I can run the block on the exchange server without a problem.
This is an example of the code i have currently
#Region create mail

# Prompt for admin credentials
$admin = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your admin credentials using your admin UPN"

# Variables
$exchangeServer = "exchange.domain.com"
$userUPN = $UserPrincipalName
$mailAddress = $UserPrincipalName
$user = $SamAccountName

# Error handling
try {
    # Connect to the Exchange server
    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://$exchangeServer/PowerShell/" -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $admin
    Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

    # Enable remote mailbox
    Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $userUPN -RemoteRoutingAddress "${user}@company.onmicrosoft.com"

    # Set remote mailbox settings with correct SMTP and disable Email Address Policy
    Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity $mailAddress -PrimarySmtpAddress $UserPrincipalName -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false

    # Display results or perform additional actions as needed
    $remoteMailbox1 = Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity $userUPN
    $remoteMailbox2 = Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity $mailAddress

    # Output the results
    Write-Output "Remote mailbox for ${userUPN}:"
    Write-Output $remoteMailbox1
    Write-Output "Remote mailbox for ${mailAddress}:"
    Write-Output $remoteMailbox2

} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
} finally {
    # Disconnect from the Exchange session
    if ($session) {
        Remove-PSSession $session
    }
}

#Endregion

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Winrm config says max connections are 300 and the server trying to connect to exchange also is a trustedhost.
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config

Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = serverItryToConnecttowardsExchange.domain.com
    Service
        RootSDDL = 
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647

I have no idea what causes this error and google/chatgpt are of no help.
What i tried is adding a dc/remove ps session cause i thought it would remove and dc the sessions. It worked at first but was a placebo cause after 99 new users 10 users would give me the error again.
Also waiting a few moments or days between creating would resolve the issue.
